# describe-table method using DocumentClient

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

How to do this request using [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)?

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name MusicCollection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document client is for working with items, but assuming you mean how do you do it with Javascript, the answer is like this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#describeTable-property

```
 var params = {
  TableName: "MusicCollection"
 };
 dynamodb.describeTable(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

Comment: You are right. Looks like I should create two variables in my lambda function - var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();